# How to generate a log file in C Language?

Tags: c

I have created a C program to log to a file with a function, but the log file is not being created.

My log file program is like...

```
int foo_handler( request_rec* inpRequest ) {
    int nReturnVal = DECLINED;

    if ( inpRequest->handler != NULL && strcmp( inpRequest->handler, "foo" ) == 0 )
    {
        ap_rputs( "Hello World from FOO", inpRequest );
        nReturnVal = OK;
    }

    return nReturnVal; }

void foo_hooks( apr_pool_t* inpPool ) {
    ap_hook_handler( foo_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE ); }


module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA foo_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    foo_hooks };
```

Comment: Why not just create a function that Open a file and then output the message into that file ?

Comment: Did you copy/paste from the wrong file by mistake?

Comment: Please explain why you want to make a log file with a C program embedded in the log.

Answer (score 3):

I'm honestly not exactly sure what your program is supposed to be doing. It might help if you include the whole thing so we can see how you're calling your functions through `main`. Regardless, if you want a logfile, the simplest way to do this would be to just output to a text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    // Open a file pointer named "log.txt" for writing (w+)
    // If you google c file i/o you'll find all the specifiers for
    // writing, reading, writing and reading, etc. I just chose
    // only writing here as an example
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("log.txt", "w");

    // Generate whatever you want logged here, "data" is just an example
    char* data = "The data to be logged...";

    // This lines writes the info in "data" to the file pointer specified
    fputs(data, fp);

    // Always remember to close your files
    fclose(fp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```